# Using inline-assembly to read the content of .rodata section of ELF binary

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, elf, inline-assembly

So I have been studying ELF binary and came across this question of whether it is possible to read the ELF data section using an inline assembly (assuming you know where the section is located).

After searching for a bit, I found a few links that asked a similar question, but I am struggling a bit to put them together for my use.

1. [Retrieving Offsets, Strings and Virtual Address in .rodata and .rodata1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919876/retrieving-offsets-strings-and-virtual-address-in-rodata-and-rodata1)
2. [x86 ASM Linux - Using the .bss Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145243/x86-asm-linux-using-the-bss-section)
3. [dword ptr usage confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688799/dword-ptr-usage-confusion)

The question I have is, let's say I have the content of a section (custom .rodata section I added using objcopy) as the following:

```
╰─$ objdump -s -j .rodata_custom hello                              ↵

hello:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata_custom:
 4ab3ac 42796520 576f726c 64                 Bye World
```

Using the inline assembly in the C program, I would like to read the content of this section (either ASCII code or string literal, whichever one is possible).

From my understanding of inline assembly, the solution I can think of is using something like the

```
mov reg, DWORD PTR [address of section] 
mov variable, reg
```

I statically compiled a binary, so I won't have to deal with relocation (although dynamically compiling won't be too much of an issue since this new data section will always be adjacent to the original .rodata section), and from disassembling the binary, I know the address of the section to read is 4ab3ac.

Here is my attempt at solving my problem:

```
int main() {
  char *test;
  uintptr_t addr = 0x4ab3ac;
  asm volatile (
    "mov %%rdx, dword ptr [%0]\n\t"
    "mov %%rdx, %[test]\n\t"
    : [test]"=a"(test)
    : "r"(addr)
    :
   );
  printf("%p\n", test);

  return 0;
}
```

and unfortunately, it results in an error stating that `` Error: junk `[%rax]' after expression ``. I feel like I'm close, but missing something or misunderstanding somewhere...

I hope my question and intent make sense.
If full code (source code + Makefile) is necessary to understand the question, please let me know.

Kind regards,

Comment: That's Intel syntax for addressing modes, but you're using `%` on register names (which matches the compiler's default `-masm=att` mode).  You could use `-masm=intel` and consistently use Intel-syntax everywhere.  Look at the compiler's asm output that it feeds to the assembler.  `gcc -S` or https://godbolt.org/.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Comment: @PeterCordes Hello, thank you for your suggestion, I was able to solve the problem using your suggestion of converting my code to Intel syntax `asm(".intel_syntax noprefix")` and then also found an AT&T equivalent version of dword ptr which was `asm("movl (%0),%%eax\n\t" : : "r"(addr) :);`